# SQL - Get a count for each hour

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mySQL that looks like this -

```
user_id |      login_date       | ip_address
   45      2016-03-28 21:18:01    111.111.111.111
   43      2016-03-28 22:18:01    122.122.122.122
```

Everytime a user logs in it will create a new entry into this table, what I want to be able to do is count the amount of logins on an hour to hour basis so when I've ran the query it will look like this.

```
   date       |      hour       | count
2016-03-28          19-20           0
2016-03-28          21-22           2
```

**For example on March 31st 2016 from the hour 09 to 10 5 people logged in whereas On March 31st 2016 from the hour 10 to 11 0 people logged in.**

Using this answer -

```
SELECT
    DATE(login_date),
    HOUR(login_date),
    COUNT(*)
FROM logins
WHERE DATE(login_date) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE(login_date),HOUR(login_date))
ORDER BY HOUR(login_date) ASC
```

Gives me -

[image]

Why am I getting NULL?

I will then use this data to create a combination chart to compare todays logins vs yesterdays

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are you counting the logins by user_id or ip_address or both?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: This isn't an hour to hour basis - if that was the case `21` would be `1` and `22` would be `1` - instead you're counting from `21:00:00` to `22:59:59` (which is 1 hour 59 minutes 59 seconds). If you want to group by hour you can use `GROUP BY DATE(login_date), HOUR(login_date)`.

Comment: @Matt I am counting logins by date...

Answer (score 0):

i think you try this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(login_date),
    HOUR(login_date),
    COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(login_date) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY CONCAT(DATE(login_date),HOUR(login_date))
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting a result like this - 0000-00-00     NULL      561

Comment: @Kieron606 add the where statement, be sure your login_date is a valid date string

Comment: My login_date is a datetime